# OnScroll Load more data

Tags: ios, tableview

I implemented search Api and its working fine in ios objective c. I am getting result from server. And again I need to call the same service when I am scroll end on tableview. And I need to pass extra parameter as **"page=2"** at same time on same page. And I need to show next page data on table view end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is pagination concept.

Please go through this link and you will get a better idea about it : [Swift tableView Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367496/swift-tableview-pagination)

I can show what I have done in my project :

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row = arrayDataForTable.count && page <= totalNumberOfPages {
        page += 1
    }
}
```

In above code arrayDataForTable contains data to show in table. If user has scrolled to last cell I am adding page count increase code. I am getting "totalNumberOfPages" from api  and maintaining page count as "page" locally starting from 0.

For Objective C use this method:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me in objective c, I am new to ios so. Thank you

Comment: @Raviteja: I have edited the answer. Try the same implementation with above mentioned delegate method.

Comment: Can you give me full code in objective c

Comment: Please tell me why a downvote ?

Comment: I too dont know