# Swift create pagination in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination

I have `UITableView` with display caching data from array

I want to make pagination on `UITableView` like this structure:

1)When I go to view with `UITableView` - it's show me all caching data (this I did and it's works)

2) When user scroll down and `if caching data left 5` call function whitch load new 10 data to array and show at the botom in `UITableView` and add recheck( when when table rows show 15 of 20 rows call function to load more data and add)

> For example : in cach array I have 10 data, function load new and in
>   table shows me 20 rows with data

I try to do this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)

        let lastItem = array.count - 1
        if indexPath.row == lastItem {
            loadMoreData()
        }
    }

 func loadMoreData {
        for _ in 0...9 {
            //load data from server
        }
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47815332/2299040

Comment: @SPatel how can I create check for  left to 5 rows at the end and need to add more data?

Comment: @SahilManchanda I dont need to send page number to server, Im need to load more

Comment: Pagination should be done from backend. You just need to pass parameters along with `pageNo` to specify for which page you want data. So after api calling you need to append data in your current data source and increase page no. count by one. Page no. count  could be managed by your own logic.

Answer (score 3):

Take one Bool Variable to check data is loading from api.

```
var isLoading = false
```

Add below code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if !isLoading && indexPath.row == array.count - 5 {
        isLoading = true
        loadMoreData()
    }
}
```

set `isLoading = false` once you get data from api.

Hope this will help you :)