# How I can implement pegination on collection view when collection view scroll? In ios

Tags: ios

I want to implement pegination in collectionview, and one refresh view just below the last item, how we can achieve this in swift 4?

Comment: This may be helpful for you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367496/swift-tableview-pagination)

Comment: What have you attempted so far, and what problems did you run into?

Comment: Thanks for your suggetion, Now i have changed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

**I have declare 2 public variable as:**

```
var page_number = 1
var total_count = 0
```

**And Edit willDisplay delegate method as:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{  
    if(indexPath.item == (arrayProperties.count - 1) && arrayProperties.count < total_count )
    {
        page_number = page_number+1

        // Call api with updated page_number
          callApi(pageNumber: page_number)
    }
}
```